# Getting error on trying to save files from post request

Tags: python, flask, post, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file i.e send a POST request. Whenever I send a file on Postman to localhost:5000/upload I'm getting internal sever error (500) and the flask app crashes with

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/2.pdf'
```

where `2.pdf` is the file I'm trying to upload. Here's the code snippet of my app

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './static/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file.filename)))
        resp = jsonify({'message': 'File successfully uploaded'})
        resp.status_code = 201
        return resp
```

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1825E.png)

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7drv.png)

Comment: Check if the relative path from the folder where you're running the flask app from works for `./static/`

Comment: Did u include `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER` ?

Comment: @rdas Woah thanks mate, the app.py and static folder were in the same location, but I was running from a higher directory on VS code, hence the error. I feel so dumb, but thanks. How do I upvote you now?

Comment: @Codenewbie is that a necessary step?

Comment: @Eeshaan Doc's suggests that :)  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: Ohh okay, I did that locally and updated the code here as well. Thanks :D